# What is the correct way to extend an existing entity in a Symfony bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have a symfony project.
In the core bundle (the appBundle) I have a User entity.

This project is used by several of my clients, and different clients need different features.

I'm trying to encapsulate a feature in a bundle, but that feature needs to add fields to the User entity in the appBundle.
I'd rather not change the appBundle but rather keep all the changes in the feature bundle.

What's the correct way to do that?

(would creating an entity in the feature bundle to hold the additional fields, and connecting it in a one to one relationship a good idea?)

Comment: I'm using doctrine orm in this project

Answer (score 0):

Assuming doctrine, have you looked into [Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)?

Your AppBundle could provide just a Mapped Superclass and the feature bundles could inherit from it.